# Can not complete codewar task: "Which color is the brightest?"

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

DESCRIPTION for a task:

One of the common ways of representing color is the RGB color model, in which the Red, Green, and Blue primary colors of light are added together in various ways to reproduce a broad array of colors.

One of the ways to determine brightness of a color is to find the value V of the alternative HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) color model. Value is defined as the largest component of a color:

V = max(R,G,B)
You are given a list of colors in 6-digit hexidecimal notation #RRGGBB. Return the brightest of these colors!

For example,

brightest(["#001000", "#000000"]) == "#001000"
brightest(["#ABCDEF", "#123456"]) == "#ABCDEF"
If there are multiple brightest colors, return the first one:

brightest(["#00FF00", "#FFFF00", "#01130F"]) == "#00FF00"
Note that both input and output should use upper case for characters A, B, C, D, E, F.

My solution:

```js
function brightest(colors){
  let colorIndex = 0,
      maxValue = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.lenght; i++) {
    let color = colors[i],
        r = ParseInt(color.slise(1,3), 16),
        g = ParseInt(color.slise(3,5), 16),
        b = ParseInt(color.slise(5,7), 16),
        value = Math.max(r,g,b)
    if (value > maxValue) {
      maxValue = value
      colorIndex = i
    }  
  }
  return colors [colorIndex]
}
```

Result:

Test failed with colors = #CAA365,#1861D3,#E8E2C6,#3D3548,#F19BBF,#BF12C3: expected '#CAA365' to deeply equal '#F19BBF'

What is wrong? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Start by fixing obvious syntax errors (`ParseInt`, `slise` etc)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable
**let** value = Math.max(r,g,b)

Answer (score 0):

length not lenght
let/var to variables
parseInt not ParseInt
slice not slise

And all will working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).